# nginx load balancer and kafka rest proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, load-balancing

I use `Kafka rest proxy` and I want `behind` `load balancer nginx`. 
I have one topic in `cluster Kafka`(three nodes) and Produce a message with JSON data

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.json.v2+json" \
          --data '{"records":[{"value":{"name": "testUser"}}]}' \
          "http://nginx_ip:8080/topics/json_test"
```

my nginx config is:

```
upstream backend {
    server 192.168.190.37:8080;
    server 192.168.190.38:8080;
    server 192.168.190.39:8080;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
    proxy_pass              http://backend;
    proxy_redirect          off;
    proxy_next_upstream     timeout;
    proxy_connect_timeout   3s;
    proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    client_max_body_size 20m;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    }
}
```

I will send an request with the `postman` but i get `404`.

```
192.168.190.1 - - [30/May/2019:13:33:59 -0400] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.11.0" "-"
```

But when I send an application to the ip server like this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.json.v2+json" \
          --data '{"records":[{"value":{"name": "testUser"}}]}' \
          "http://192.168.190.37:8080/topics/json_test"
```

There is no problem. 
How do I use nginx load balancer for Kafka rest proxy and producer different topics?